Maximum depth intersecting building resets with iterate function after first file using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder
I am using ArcGIS Pro.
I have exported polygon files for different group runs with depth information from ICM, I am then using a building layer to identify the maxdepth intersecting to each building as polygons can intersect from different corners therefore the max value is needed.
I have used ModelBuilder to do this using the iterate function and the depth=max function in fields.
However after the first file is completed depth=max resets to its initial status depth=first, therefore the values I get after my first file are the first ones intersecting instead of max.
Is there a way to change that?


I have spoofed up a simple model, in ArcPro 3.3.2 as shown below that returns the maximum value of a field called depth. I am joining a point dataset to a polygon dataset.

The results are as expected.

I note from your screen shot you are using an older version of ArcPro, try upgrading to the latest version.
